# How to call javascript function from Django template tag

Tags: javascript, django

I'm trying to get the tab history length into url tag to pass it as parameter.
What I tried in template (and didn't work out) is this:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'polls:load_zip' javascript:history.length %}">Query</a></li>
```

I also tried to create a javascript function and call it from the url tag but it didn't work out as well:

```
<script>
function history_len(){   
    return history.length;  
}
</script>
```

and

```
<li><a href="{% url 'polls:load_zip' history_len() %}">Query</a></li>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't use client side code when rendering something server side

Comment: @Sayse do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Where does "history" come from?

Comment: from the client side, not sure specifically

Comment: you need to use ajax to send the history to a view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use anything like that in URL then you have to add URL hardcoded.

```
<li><a class="ref_link" href="#">Query</a></li>

<script>
      $('.ref_link').attr("href",'/example/url'+history.length);  
</script>
```

you can use something like this.